# How do we understand the relationship between independent probabilities and real-world independence?

Tags: probability, independence, mathematical-statistics

From what I have come to understand, the events A and B are considered independent for purposes of probability theory when

$$
p(A \cap B) = p(A) \cdot p(B)
$$

Now, supposing I flip two coins. I write down the probabilities for the joint outcomes as $\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\right)$ and see that the individual coins are independent. But how do we know those probabilities? Well, the first coin could come up either heads or tails with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, then in the case of heads we know that the probabilities for the second coin are still $\frac{1}{2}$… but this seems to be assuming $p(A|B) = p(A)$, which is mathematically just a rearrangement of the above formula, so this feels like circular reasoning.

So, what's the explanation? Why does theoretical independence correspond to practical independence, in a not-apparently-circular way?

Comment: Real world independence?. When occurrence and non occurrence of a particular object does not depend on occurrence and non occurrence of another object is called the independence of these objects. In real world where this definition stand statistical independence and real world independence are same.

Comment: By 'real world independence' do you mean something like 'physically independent' or something else? Independence in the probability sense is a jargon term with a very specific meaning which applies to probability models -- mathematical constructs which needn't relate to anything in the real world at all.

Comment: You've assumed independence when constructing the joint distribution.

Comment: In the real world the impact of the lack of complete independence (things like the [butterfly effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)) is probably less substantial than the lack of precise fairness, i.e. the probability of heads is almost certainly not exactly 1/2.

Comment: I think you need to expand on what you mean by "circularity" in your penultimate paragraph. Let X and Y be Bernouilli random variables for coin flips and writing h for head and t for tail, we have P(X=h)=P(X=t)=½, and also P(Y=h)=P(Y=t)=½. By the first formula you quoted, P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y), so P(X=h,Y=h) = P(X=h)P(Y=h) = ½ x ½ = 1/4. Similar reasoning yields 1/4 for the other probabilities. This doesn't assume P(A|B) = P(A), so there is no circularity.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I did not ask the question clearly: what is it about the laws of the universe that causes it to the the case that X=h and Y=h are independent in the probability theory sense?

Comment: Glen_b, that is exactly what is puzzling me: the probability theory definition of independent is technical and narrow, and yet I do observe that it does, somehow, apply to the real world case of tossing two coins in the air. Why does it? jtobin, yes, that is what I meant by that my reasoning was circular.

Comment: @Owen FYI you need to write an at sign in front of a user's name for them to get a notification. I don't know who your first comment is directed at (me?), and Glen_b won't have got a notification for your second comment. If you edit or replace your comments you should be ok (and I'll delete this one).

Comment: Would it be too far-fetched to suppose that people develop theories and concepts to describe what they observe, and therefore what they observe actually *does* tend sometimes to conform to those theories? :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think if you approach it the other way around it is more intuitively understandable. What does it mean that two variables $A$ and $B$ are independent? It means that knowing the probability distribution/function of one **tells us absolutely nothing** about the other one. The fact that $B$ may or may not have occurred is irrelevant, extraneous, and pretty much distracting when we are thinking of $A$. What does this mean in probabilistic terms? It means that the probability of $A$ occurring, given that $B$ occurred is the same as the probability of $A$ ignoring $B$ completely. We translate this English (or whatever language you wish) concept into symbolic mathematical form as $P(A|B) = P(A)$. This is the root expression, not the product rule, as this is the translation into mathematical symbols of the meaning of the word "independent".

Now that we have defined/translated "independence" to mean $P(A|B) = P(A)$, we can make the following observation:
$$
P(A|B) = P(A)\\
\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A)\\
P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)
$$
The "product rule" is an outgrowth (via algebraic manipulation) of the definition, not the other way around.

Comment: What you say makes sense intuitively and is a really nice way of explaning it, but I quibble on "not the other way round". In fact I have seen independence defined via $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, and for pdfs, $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. In the discrete case, starting from **(1)** $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, and the definition of conditional probability **(2)** $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$, you can then substitute **(1)** into **(2)** to get $P(A|B) = P(A)$.

Comment: I've seen it that way too, but I harken back to my bible on Probability, DeGroot 2ed, and where he introduces the concept of independence (ch. 1.11), the explanations are of the form (paraphrased p. 44) _since X and Y are unrelated, the sample space is the product of the individual outcomes *each equally possible*_… Which is just the way to say in English $P(A|B) = P(A)$, so I think that even if the independence is defined as the product rule, it is always justified (sometimes only implicitly) using the conditional definition. (Larson 1982 pp.70-71) defines it explicitly using conditionals.

Comment: @TooTone References for above comment: [DeGroot, M. H. Probability and Statistics Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, 1986](http://amzn.to/12TYJgj) and [Larson, H. Introduction to Probability Theory and Statistical Inference Wiley, 1982](http://amzn.to/19T759S)

Comment: I like your way of explaining it, but I do not think that this answers my question. Why is the translation in question (from colloquial "provides no information" to the equation) a faithful one? That is really what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Your explanation is nice but it runs into difficulties when $P(B)=0$. The definition and concept of conditional independence are complicated and difficult in this case, whereas a formula like $P(A\cap B) =P(A)P(B)$ is simple and clear.

Comment: @whuber Agreed that the product is simple and clear. Moreover, in many textbooks, independence is introduced before conditional probability. However, I don't think it changes the _implicit_ assumption of conditionality. As for the case of $P(B) = 0$, in that case $P(A|B)$ is a logical contradiction, and false antecedents (B occurring) imply any consequents for that matter.

Comment: @Owen, let me reverse the question. Why is $P(Heads = \frac{1}{2}$ a faithful translation of the probability of a fair coin? Why is $x = x_0 + vt + \frac{1}{2}at^2$ a faithful translation of the position of a particle under constant acceleration? What allows you to accept the former and not this? Understanding what exactly troubles you about this concept will help in addressing it.

Comment: I believe you are implicitly limiting your discussion to *discrete* variables, Avraham. In general, $P(A|B)$ can exist and is not a "logical contradiction" even when $P(B)=0$. An important application concerns conditional probabilities like $P(X|Y)$ where $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal. In this case $P(Y=y)=0$ for all real numbers $y$, yet $X|Y=y$ has a normal distribution. It may also be worth remarking that conditional probabilities assert nothing about *temporal sequence,* whence explanations using phrases like "$A$ ... given that $B$ occurred" are often misunderstood by beginners.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a problem where you say you "observe the two coins are independent."  You never *observe* probabilistic independence, per se; it is always a property of the events / random variables under consideration, which are *constructed* by the modeller to represent some (physical or otherwise) phenomenon.

So, the physical phenomenon here is: there are two fair coins, and tossing either one of them does not affect the outcome of the other.  They're 'independent' in a nontechnical sense, if you want to use that word.

A probabilistic model that we can build to represent this physical phenomenon mathematically is: **define** two independent, Bernoulli(1/2)-distributed random variables $X_{0}$ and $X_{1}$.  I.e.,

$$
X_{0}, X_{1} \overset{iid}\sim \text{bernoulli}(1/2) \\
$$

Here I mean 'independent' in the technical, probabilistic sense.  That gives us stuff like

$$
P(\{X_{0} = 1\}\cap\{X_{1} = 1\} = P(X_{0} = 1)P(X_{1}=1)
$$

and we can get the joint distribution by enumerating all the combinations of $X_{0}$ and $X_{1}$, as you've done.  Nothing circular to be found.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this some more, I believe the answer is entropy maximization. The entropy of the joint distribution is highest when the two coins are independent.

Comment: The entropy can be regarded as the amount of missing information. Any known dependence or correlation between A and B reduces the amount of missing information. Thus, no correlation or dependence maximizes the entropy.

Comment: Yes. The important part is that entropy maximization is true in physics, explaining why the real world produces probabilities that match the arithmetic definition of independence.